# phonegap: Couldn't encode image to base64 on android 2.3

Tags: cordova

I have an issue in encoding images to base64 with phonegap, I tested the code over android 4 and iOS devices and it is working fine but when I tested it on android version 2.3 it didn't work.
here is my code:

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        c.width = this.width;
        c.height = this.height;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataUri = c.toDataURL("image/png");

       alert(dataUri);
    };
    img.src = filePath;
```

the output of this code on android 2.3 is always empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it isn't supported in your version, have a look at this issue reported

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16829

There is supposed to be some sort of JavaScript implementation to add support for it, but i haven't tried it myself

http://code.google.com/p/todataurl-png-js/

Comment: I tested this solution before but the issue is that this code is very slow on android 2.3, do you have any other solution?

Comment: sorry this is all i know

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using [phonegap-base64](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64) plugin